# Remove closing tag XML root with PHP

Tags: php, xml, removechild

I would like to remove the closing tag of an XML file. 
Currently I am using simplexml to load the file.
I've looked at removeChild but haven't found a good example of somebody using it to remove the closing tag of the root.

I currently have:

```
<root>
    <tag>
        <info1>Some info</info1>
        <info2>Some info</info2>
    </tag>
</root>
```

Would become:

```
<root>
    <tag>
        <info1>Some info</info1>
        <info2>Some info</info2>
    </tag>
```

I would like to do this without too much difficulty, anybody know how?

EDIT: 
I've solved this as stated in the comments.
Using simpleXML was not required as I should have stated in my question.

Comment: Won't that result in broken XML?

Comment: It will, but I am later adding it back in before writing it back to the file.

Comment: If you are sure it always ends with that tag on the last line of the file, you could just strip the last line of the file away.

Comment: Depending on what you actually want to achive an external entity or an xinclude may solve your problem. That would be something like `...</tag><xi:include href="someurl" parse="xml" /></root>` or `...</tag>&extratags;</root>`

Comment: @Tyil I solved it by changing the method of reading the file, and getting it as text instead of a simpleXML object. After that I just remove the </root> tag with str_replace and add in the new content. (not perfect I know, but works as expected)

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the method of reading the file, and getting it as text instead of a simpleXML object. After that I just remove the  tag with str_replace and add in the new content. (not perfect I know, but works as expected)

Answer (score 0):

Actually an XML parser like SimpleXML is not able to create invalid XML, therefore this is not an option.

However it is obviously the last line. Therefore you can search for the second last line-separator and cut the end away. That should easily do it. As you write that is SimpleXML, when you return the XML as string the line separator is `"\xA"` (for US-ASCII/ISO-8859-1/UTF-8 encoded XML files, normally the case):

```
$xml  = $simpleXml->asXML();
$last = strrpos($xml, "\xA", -2);
if ($last === false) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException('Can not find beginning of last line.');
}
echo substr($xml, 0, $last), "\n";
```

[Demo](http://eval.in/private/93811682699c15)

This is nothing really strictly well written, however might be just fitting for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you want to add data to your existing simplexml-object? Other approaches that keep your data valid:

1. use simplexml's add-methods.
2. read from simplexml with a loop and write to a new file with xmlwriter, add your new xml data before you send the command to close the root-element.